# There is a duplicate directory in github repository after renaming directories

Tags: git, android-studio, github, gitlab, github-actions

I have a "models" folder in my project. It was previously name as "Models" so I renamed it to "models" and then I push the code in the github repository. everything is fine the local project but in the  github repository there are two folder now. One is "Models" and another is "models".

This is the screenshot of the project in android studio:

[image]

and this is the screenshot github repository:
[image]

As you would see, There is extra folder in github repository named as "Models"

How can I fix this??

Comment: are you running Windows or MacOS ? (with a case insensitive file system ?)

Comment: I am running Windows

Comment: It is case sensitive

Comment: Run `git rm -r --cached Models`, check that `git status models/` doesn't report deletion, if ok commit the result

Comment: for the record : on Linux, you can have a `CONFIG.INI` file sitting next to a `Config.ini` file in the same directory. On Windows, you cannot -- they are both considered the same file. A file has a recorded name with possibly upper- and lowercase letters, but the filesystem is case insensitive : you can't create two files whith differences only in casing, when a program to open file `config.ini`, the system will answer "ok" and open `Config.ini` or `CONFIG.INI`.